# Automatic file and folder naming

Tags: fortran

I am a new Fortran user. I am trying to create a file name according to date and time. I only know the command for opening fie which is:

```
open (unit=10,file='test.txt')
```

I want to have a file name instead of `'test.txt'` using the current date and time when program execute. If anyone can help me I will be grateful then.

Comment: It seems your problem is not about creating a file, but creating a file name based on date and time values, said otherwise you need to create a string based on date and time, which in turn is a problem of concatenation. See [this example](http://www.cs.mtu.edu/~shene/COURSES/cs201/NOTES/chap02/char-opr.html) for a solution.

Comment: While the problem seems to be solved, it would appear to me that it would have been an option to use `write (10,*)` to output to a file called `fort.10`, and then rename the file when you run the executable, or put it in your makefile.

Answer (score 2):

You can use [`date_and_time`](https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gfortran/DATE_005fAND_005fTIME.html) to achieve this:

```
module time_ftcs

contains
  function timestamp() result(str)
    implicit none
    character(len=20)                     :: str
    integer                               :: values(8)
    character(len=4)                      :: year
    character(len=2)                      :: month
    character(len=2)                      :: day, hour, minute, second
    character(len=5)                      :: zone

    ! Get current time
    call date_and_time(VALUES=values, ZONE=zone)  
    write(year,'(i4.4)')    values(1)
    write(month,'(i2.2)')   values(2)
    write(day,'(i2.2)')     values(3)
    write(hour,'(i2.2)')    values(5)
    write(minute,'(i2.2)')  values(6)
    write(second,'(i2.2)')  values(7)

    str = year//'-'//month//'-'//day//'_'&
          //hour//':'//minute//':'//second
  end function timestamp
end module

program test
  use time_ftcs, only: timestamp 

  open (unit=10,file='test'//trim(timestamp())//'.txt')
  write(10,*) 'Hello World'
  close(10)
end program
```

This results in a file

```
$cat test2015-04-05_09:32:27.txt
 Hello World
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use the intrinsic subroutine `date_and_time` to achieve this:

```
module time_ftcs

contains
  function timestamp() result(str)
    implicit none
    character(len=15)                     :: str
    character(len=8)                      :: dt
    character(len=10)                     :: tm

    ! Get current time
    call date_and_time(DATE=dt, TIME=tm)  

    str = dt//'_'//tm(1:6)  ! tm(7:10) are milliseconds and decimal point

  end function timestamp
end module

program test
  use time_ftcs, only: timestamp 

  open (unit=10,file='test_'//timestamp//'.txt')
  write(10,*) 'Hello World'
  close(10)
end program
```

This should result in a file

```
$cat test_20150405_093227.txt
 Hello World
```